# MATLAB Populate matrix with elements from a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, double, cell

I have a matrix and I want to put into the third column of the matrix, elements from a cell array. How can I do this?

Here is an example of what I mean. 
This is the matrix (E):

```
43.4350000000000    -88.5277780000000   NaN 733144
43.4350000000000    -88.5277780000000   NaN 733146
43.4350000000000    -88.5277780000000   NaN 733148
43.4350000000000    -88.5277780000000   NaN 733150
```

I want to take the NaN column (column 3) and put into it, the elements of a cell array (uID)
The cell array looks like this:

```
'027-0007'
'079-0026'
'119-8001'
'133-0027'
```

I used this code:

```
E(:,3) = reshape(repmat(uID',length(all_dates),1),[],1)
```

to replicate each line of uID a certain number of times and then reshape it into a column so that's it's the same size as a column of E.

However, when I run it now, the fact that E is a matrix and uID is a cell causes MATLAB to tell me that`Conversion to double from cell is not possible`. The part to the right of the `=` works fine. It's the placing the cell elements into E that's causing the problem.

Comment: The cell contains _strings_, whereas the destination matrix must contain _numbers_. How do you want to transform for example `'027-0007'` into a number? Would that be 20? Or 270007? Or...?

Comment: Also, why do you need to `repmat` the cell array? Its size seems to fit the column size in your example

Comment: 027-0007 is not a number. It's a siteID. That's why I'm having this problem. My example is only a small part of a much larger array which is why I'm using repmat. The actual array is 376x4.

Comment: You can only fill a matrix with numbers, not with siteID's (strings)

Comment: This is part of a larger question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390103/matlab-create-table-with-nans-inserted-based-on-date-column). Could you maybe take a look at that one then? If I can't fill a matrix with strings, I can't check for consistency across dates and SiteIDs to fill in data or add in NaN. The answer given for that question has a good approach, but runs into this problem.

Comment: If you want to store numbers in one column and strings in another column, you can define `E` as a cell array instead of a matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting the data into a normal matrix, you can insert it into another cell

```
  Ecell=num2cell(E); 
  Ecell(:,3)=uID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your cell array are not numeric and therefore cannot be inserted into a numeric matrix. You can use str2double to convert strings cell arrays to numeric arrays like in the following

```
 >> str2double({'3','17.5'})

ans =

    3.0000   17.5000
```

but that's only when the string contents of the cell represent actual numbers, which doesn't seem to be true in your case.

Comment: YEah, they aren't numbers. They are siteIDs so I have to keep them in that format.